# What 'LockFile' is for in Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2

From [apache2 doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile):

> The LockFile directive sets the path to the lockfile used when Apache is used with an AcceptMutex value of either fcntl or flock.

And about [AcceptMutex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#acceptmutex)

> The AcceptMutex directives sets the method that Apache uses to serialize multiple children accepting requests on network sockets.

I am running apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi for a django website on an Ubuntu 64bit box.

what is it for? is this even ever used?

I can't find a file in the specified location.

My `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V` tells me:

```
-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
-D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
```

which should mean that `sysvsem` is used. Does that mean that `LockFile` is not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile says:

> ```
> The LockFile directive sets the path to the lockfile used when Apache
> ```
>
> is used with an AcceptMutex value of
>   either fcntl or flock. This directive
>   should normally be left at its default
>   value. The main reason for changing it
>   is if the logs directory is NFS
>   mounted, since the lockfile must be
>   stored on a local disk. The PID of the
>   main server process is automatically
>   appended to the filename.

Brief version: do not touch, unless the file would end up on an NFS-mounted files ystem.

If you do not find the file where you expect/set it to be, it may mean, that AcceptMutex isn't set to neither fcnl nor flock. This may be optimal or not, depending on your architecture, as documented here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html.

Comment: thank Pawel, the latter is what interests me the most :-) . I edited my question, it looks like my Ubuntu box is using `sysvsem`. Does that mean that LockFile is simply unused - and another mechanism for locking is used instead?

Comment: Yes, your system should use SysV-style semaphores, and in that case this file is not used.

Comment: Thanks again. Reading about this on the apache perf tuning page I see it's a method that has several drawbacks. would you advise changing it?

Comment: I only have 1 port I listen to (but i sometimes experiment with multiple apache2 instances, which might be subject to another question).

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not an Apache expert, I will not tell you which method is best, because I don't know and don't want to mislead you. Looking at the different options described on the page, it looks that you could benefit from migrating off this one if you use CGI scripts. OTOH there is a warning that this section wasn't updated for Apache 2.x. My advice would be to seek a good source of information. :)

Comment: :-) which is what I was hoping to get on serverfault but so far you've been the only one trying to help! I'll try a separate question for best config with specific requirements.